# Java 11: Local-Variable Syntax for Lambda Parameters - applications

Tags: java, lambda, annotations, var, java-11

I am curious about [Java-11](https://dzone.com/articles/an-early-look-at-features-targeted-for-java-11) in general, but specifically [JEP:323](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/323) which plans to add the `var` declaration to Lambda operation variables.

The motivation behind this feature is discussed nicely [here](https://medium.com/@afinlay/java-11-sneak-peek-local-variable-type-inference-var-extended-to-lambda-expression-parameters-e31e3338f1fe).
Consider the following quote from the article:

```
// #1 - Legal
ITest divide = (@ATest var x, final var y) ->  x / y;
/* #2 Modifiers on Old-Style implicit paramaters => Illegal */
ITest divide = (@ATest x, final y) ->  x / y;
```

The usage of the final modifier is clear to me and is in line with immutability best practices.

However, I am not sure about the annotations. What is the great benefit of being able to annotate a lambda implicit parameter?

Can you provide a de-facto, beneficial example of using annotations on a lambda operation variable? Not as a matter of opinion, but as an actual example of code which is more readable or efficient when using this feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the great benefit of being able to annotate a lambda implicit parameter?

The usage of annotations within lambda statement should be similar to any other attribute on a non-lambda statement. This could be to make use of:

- reflection and infer some information about the annotated object at runtime.
- also at compile time to depict behaviors such as generated source code or other hints for tools

A use case stated in the ***[JEP-323](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/323)*** itself(reiterating myself of not being sure if that's what you're looking forward to) -

```
(@Nonnull var x, @Nullable var y) -> x.process(y)
```

where the annotations can be used by the libraries to determine a value check over `x` and `y`. In that, you know `x.process(y)` can certainly not throw a NullPointerException *without even placing an explicit null check for `x`* now which is same as any other explicitly annotated non-lambda parameter.

Notably, this is one of the benefits of bringing in the uniformity of allowing `var` for the formal parameters of an implicitly typed lambda expression.