# Java 11 Local-Variable Type Inference Improvement Usage

Tags: java, lambda, var, java-11

I am trying to make a use case for the Java 11 extension on var keyword for lambda expressions. The examples I could find online are always related to @NonNull annotation. However when I want to do something like this:

```
long count = Stream.of(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
            .filter((@NegativeOrZero var a) ->  a > -3)
            .count();

System.out.println(count);
```

I get:

> 7

I expect to count only -2, -1 and 0 and not count others, or throw an error or something. Same goes for the following:

```
long count = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null, 7, 8, 9)
            .filter((@NotNull(message="It is a null!!") var a) ->  a > 5)
            .count();

 System.out.println(count);
```

I get an NPE without any custom message unless I change `a > 5` to `a != null && a > 5` which is not related to annotation.

Can someone explain what am I missing here?

Edit: Maybe I forgot to mention but can you provide an example with var keyword and validations combined to understand its benefits?

Edit 2: I found a more simple example that is supposed to throw an error. However, for me, it returns true. I am using JDK 13 btw.

```
Predicate<String> predicate = (@NotNull var a) -> true;
System.out.println(predicate.test(null));
```

Comment: from where you get `@NegativeOrZero`

Comment: @YCF_L from ```javax.validation.constraints``` package.

Comment: You can find a [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225672/java-11-local-variable-syntax-for-lambda-parameters-applications) and the usage of these annotations by libraries generating code at compile time doesn't seem to be yet implemented, hence the lack of applications as you seek.

Comment: @Naman This abstract example doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.stream` classes are not in any way related to `javax.validation` so the stream won't understand or process `@NotNull` or `@NegativeOrZero`. When you annotate type you only provide the metadata. Something has to process this metadata to create the desired behavior, and stream does not.

Your examples are evaluated as:

```
Stream.of(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
      .filter((var a) -> a > -3)
      .count(); // 7 as only -3 is filtered out
```

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null, 7, 8, 9)
      .filter((var a) -> a > 5) // NPE on boxing null
      .count();
```

Comment: I understand that but I don't understand how to benefit from validations with var and lambda combined. Can you provide an example of usage?

Comment: `javax.validation` annotations are part of JSR 380 and require something to process them, see [this example](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation#programmatic). I never seen anyone using these annotations inside core java streams, there is nothing in core java that would process them.

Comment: Okay, I understand but then what type of annotations can I use? I tried Lombok and Spring but I couldn't make them work. I just need an example...

Comment: @OkanMenevşeoğlu Lombok is a compile time  `javac` annotation processor, Spring is mostly runtime proxies (there is also AspectJ, CGLIB, ASM, other). Start by understanding how are annotations applied before using them.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible use cases to pre-filter null values with Local-Variable Syntax for Lambda Parameters can be done by using JetBrains annotations.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations/18.0.0

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long cnt = Stream.of(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, null, 1)
            .filter((@NotNull var i) -> i > 5)
            .count();

    System.out.println(cnt);
}
```

Will yield `IllgalArgumentException` instead of `NullPointerException` at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'i' of com/app/App.lambda$main$0 must not be null
    at com.app.App.$$$reportNull$$$0(App.java)
    at com.app.App.lambda$main$0(App.java)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
```

As said at this time `javax.constraint.*` annotations won't be automagically performed as a validation against the lambda parameter. With time, I'm sure, more and more libraries, such as static code analyzers or compile time checker tools, will leverage http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/323 feature and will support that.